# How to read first line of ints in a text file, use those numbers, then go to the second line and repeat until the end of the file

Tags: java, tree, int, text-files

This is my main method. I am trying to read the first line of integers (5 4 3 7 8 4 3 1 3  ) from a text file. I want to then run those numbers through the methods i am calling in my main method. I then want to go to the next line in the text file (15 1 60 1 43 24 3), also run these numbers through the methods I am calling and so on until I reach the end of the text file. What is the best way to implement something like this? How I my code now will run through all of the integers in the text file and then run them through the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
    try 
    { 
        int num;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
        while(reader.hasNextInt())
        {
            num = reader.nextInt(); 
            if(tree.contains(num))
            {
                tree.remove(num);
            }
            else
            {
            tree.add(num);
            }
        }
       reader.close();
       tree.preorder(root);
       System.out.println();
       tree.inorder(root);
       System.out.println();
       tree.postorder(root);
       System.out.println("\nTotal: " + tree.size(root));
       System.out.println("Height: " + tree.height(root));
       System.out.println("Max: " + tree.getMax(root));
       System.out.println("Min: " + tree.getMin(root));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
  }
```

This is the text file that I want to use called numbers.txt

5 4 3 7 8 4 3 1 3

15 1 60 1 43 24 3

25 28 71 18 48 35 97

6 41 24 40 85 2 92 72 86 59 7 40

76 19 23 40 84 6 67 41 34 66 79 11 38 5 61 60 64 5

81 8 30 80 88 38 90 55 37 45 70 32 41 26

Comment: You've posted requirements and code but have asked no specific question. Please fix this so that we can know how to help you.

Comment: Start by using `Scanner#nextLine` to read a line of text, then, using another `Scanner`, use your `hasNextInt` loop to parse that

Comment: use the scanner to read a line of text, then use split to split into individual numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I would try something more like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] temp = reader.nextLine().split("\\s+"); // Regex for any and all whitespace used as a delimiter
        for (int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
            // Iterate through each element in the string array temp
        }
        // Resume while loop.
    }

}
```